# JavaScript Namespaces Converted from

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces, converters

I have this code in C# and I need to change it for JavaScript... How I do it?

```
Using System;
using UnityEngine;

Namespace UnityStandardAssets.Effects
{
    public class WaterHoseParticles : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static float lastSoundTime;
        public float force = 1;


        private ParticleCollisionEvent[] m_CollisionEvents = new ParticleCollisionEvent[16];
        private ParticleSystem m_ParticleSystem;


        private void Start()
        {
            m_ParticleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read the Unity docs? Stackoverflow is not a code translation service.

Comment: i had but i dont find none where you have a class inside a namespace

Comment: Well Javascript is a completely different language to C#, why are you trying to compare them like that at all?

Comment: for a college work that i need to do in javascript

Comment: @EmanuelCorreia The requirement is Javascript in your college? The requirement is usually C# or C++ with opengl....

Comment: @EmanuelCorreia Gave my answer. Please read the **note** under the answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript does not use `namespace` in Unity. You can and **SHOULD** learn Javascript for Unity [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/newbie-guide-to-unity-javascript-long.34015/). You will likely have hard time in the future if you don't.

The C# script in your question converted to Javascript looks like something below:

```
#pragma strict

public static var lastSoundTime : float = 0;
public var force:float = 1;

private var m_CollisionEvents : ParticleCollisionEvent[] = new ParticleCollisionEvent[16];
private  var m_ParticleSystem : ParticleSystem;

function Start () {
    m_ParticleSystem = this.gameObject.GetComponent(ParticleSystem);
}

function Update () {

}
```

**Note**:

If Javascript is required as your programming language for GD, in your class, ask your professor if you can use C#. Sometimes, you have to ask. If your professor refuses, you are probably in the wrong college.

Now, if you are that type that refuses to learn C# because you already know Javascript, you are wasting your time.

Comment: the class is about javascript and html but the teacher let us do the project on unity but with javascript and thaks for the help

Comment: @EmanuelCorreia That's weird. web design class with Unity..... Anyways, you still need to read that link I posted. It shows you how to use Javascript with Unity. If my answer solved your problem, you can accept it as the solution. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png